# Error while exporting Component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was exporting a React.js Component (Comp.jsx) to App.js (the main file) and 
got this error.

> Error: ./src/App.js Attempted import error: './Components/Comp.jsx' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Comp').

Comp.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
function MyInfo() {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My Name</h1>
            <p>This is a Para</p>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyInfo/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Comp from './Components/Comp.jsx';


function App() {
  return (
    <Comp>Hello World</Comp>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also export the MyInfo Component.
The MyInfo Component/function is only declared and not exported.
Put

`export default MyInfo`

at the bottom of the Comp.jsx file
or

`export default function MyInfo()...`

where the function is declared
. This way the MyInfo component can be imported and used in other files.
Also the ReactDOM.render must be in the App.jsx file. See https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-fermi-44r26

Comment: I am unable to see any MyInfo.jsx file. Tried 'export default MyInfo' in  Comp.jsx and still  getting the same error.

Comment: I've edited my answer... what happens when you add export default? Is the path to the components folder correct?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the 'export default MyInfo' and the error is still the same. Also, the path is correct.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/reverent-fermi-44r26 . The render must be in the App component

Comment: Okay Got it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyInfo/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Move that to `App.js` file and render `App`.

App.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

OR

Add `export default` in `Comp.jsx`.

Comp.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

// \/ here
export default function MyInfo() {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My Name</h1>
            <p>This is a Para</p>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyInfo/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```